# AngularJS : Accessing parent scope in a transcluded directive that contains nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

I am working on a basic directive that creates a grid of divs that fits with Bootstrap. You give it a collection of items and optionally specify the number of columns it can contain. It is transcluded so you can define the template displayed for each item.

I break the collection into rows, and then have nested repeaters where the first creates each row, and the second creates each column (and then transcludes the content for that item). It works well in this simple scenario.

```
 .directive('grid', [function() {
    return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            template: '<div class="row" ng-repeat="row in rows"><div ng-repeat="item in row" ng-class="{\'col-md-{{columnSpan}}\': true, \'active\': isSelected(item) }"><div class="thumbnail" ng-transclude=""></div></div></div>',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                items: '=grid',
                columns: '@',
                columnSpan: '@'
            },
            controller: [
                '$scope', function($scope) {
                }
            ],
            link: function($scope, $el, $attrs) {
                $attrs.$observe('columns', function(val) {
                    $scope.columns = val || 4;
                });

                $attrs.$observe('columnSpan', function(val) {
                    $scope.columnSpan = val || 12 / $scope.columns;
                });

                $scope.$watchCollection('items', function(items) {
                    $scope.rows = $scope.rows || [];
                    $scope.rows.length = 0;

                    if (!items) return;

                    var numRows = Math.floor(items.length / $scope.columns);
                    numRows = items.length % $scope.columns !== 0 ? numRows + 1 : numRows;

                    for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
                        var row = items.slice(i * $scope.columns, (i + 1) * $scope.columns);
                        $scope.rows.push(row);
                    }

                });
            }
    };
  }]);
```

The problem is in the transcluded content, I sometimes need to invoke a function or access an item from the parent scope. For example, say I want to format a display name, or add a click handler.

```
<!-- addHello is defined on the controller scope. this doesn't work -->
<div grid="items" columns="3">
  {{addHello(item) || 'Undefined'}} (name is {{item.name}})
</div>
```

Because this creates multiple transcluded scopes, I have to unnest the scope by chaining `$parent` until I eventually find it.

```
<!-- works, but ಠ_ಠ -->
<div grid="items" columns="3">
  {{$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.addHello(item) || 'Undefined'}} (name is {{item.name}})
</div>
```

This also works, but it's awkward and violates law of Demeter, which is important because if I change how this works internally in the future, it'd potentially break the transcluded content. How can I improve this to avoid this issue?

[Fully functional plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q9wGzuh5T7J6BHhbfg4X?p=preview).

Comment: Btw, is your account really hacked or it is just an ID?...Just curious... :)

Comment: @zsong Hah, no. It's a reference to [Code Red](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Red_(computer_worm))

Answer (score 2):

Use delegate pattern. The idea is to expose a customizable function in the directive and let the real action to be plugged in. The action will be triggered inside the transcluded scope calling the function belongs to the parent scope.

```
<div grid="items" columns="3" custom-action="addHello"> //addHello() belongs to the DemoCtrl's scope 
    {{doAction(item) || 'Undefined'}} (name is {{item.name}}) //doAction() belongs to the translcuded scope
</div>
```

And update the directive to something like this:

```
scope: {
    ...
    customAction: "&"
},
link: function($scope, $el, $attrs) {

    ...

    $scope.doAction = function(item){
        return $scope.customAction(item);
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yl3SkrcoFW0NedPZ8YlG?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: doesn't this defy the whole idea of transclusion because now the transcluded element is dependent on directive's scope. I am just thinking out loud. :)

Comment: @dmahapatro Based on this use case, this is one possible solution since you have to touch both sides. The best way is use delegate pattern to clearly separate logic.

Comment: I had thought of this, and it certainly works if you have a limited (and expected) set of actions you want to expose. However, if I make this control generally reusable, this solution would be untenable without forking and modifying it to poke the holes for the actions you needed.